# How can I overcome this static reference to non-static field error?

Tags: java

In the following code, I'm getting the error 'Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field MainFrame.lambdaD'. Can I overcome this without changing lambdaD to static and if so how?

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.XYSplineRenderer;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeries;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeriesCollection;



/**
 *
 * @authors George and Stephen Tomlinson
 */
public class Graph extends Applet{

    // set version number

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /*
       Method which takes an ArrayList array defining 2 data sets and produces a JFreeChart
       graphing them and adds this to a JPanel which is then used by the createandShowGUI method to 
       define the contents of a JFrame GUI and then display it. The method returns this JPanel.
     */

    public JPanel createContentPane(ArrayList<Double>[] in){

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        XYSeries seriesTrue = new XYSeries("True");
        XYSeries seriesApprx = new XYSeries("Approx");

        // Read input arguments and store in XYSeries objects.

         for(int i=0;i<in[0].size();i++)
         {
             double item = (double)in[0].get(i);
             seriesTrue.add(i,item);
         }

         for(int i=0;i<in[1].size();i++)
         {
             double item = (double)in[1].get(i);
             seriesApprx.add(i,item);
         }        

        XYSeriesCollection dataset = new XYSeriesCollection();
        XYSeriesCollection datasetApprx = new XYSeriesCollection();
        dataset.addSeries(seriesTrue);
        datasetApprx.addSeries(seriesApprx);

        double lambda = MainFrame.lambdaD;

        // Create a chart from the first data set (the true solution). 

        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart(
                "Plot of true and approx solns of y' = -" + lambda+ "*y",
                "time",
                "y",
                dataset, 
                PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,
                true,
                true,
                false
                );

        ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);

        // Add the second data set (the approximate solution) to the chart (the first is at index 0).

        chart.getXYPlot().setDataset(1, datasetApprx);

        /*
         Create a separate renderer for each data set (otherwise they won't be recognised as separate
         data sets, so the JFreeChart object won't give them different colours for example, as it only
         sees one data set, so refuses to assign any more than one colour to it.  
         * */

        XYSplineRenderer SR0 = new XYSplineRenderer(1000);

        XYSplineRenderer SR1 = new XYSplineRenderer(1000);

        chart.getXYPlot().setRenderer(0, SR0); 

        chart.getXYPlot().setRenderer(1, SR1); 

        // Set colours for each data set.

        chart.getXYPlot().getRendererForDataset(chart.getXYPlot().getDataset(0)).setSeriesPaint(0, Color.BLUE);

        chart.getXYPlot().getRendererForDataset(chart.getXYPlot().getDataset(1)).setSeriesPaint(0, Color.RED);

        panel.add(chartPanel);

        panel.setOpaque(true); 

        return panel;  
    }

    // Method to create the GUI upon which the graph is displayed, which takes an ArrayList array (called i)
    // of length 2 containing the 2 data sets to be graphed.

    public void createAndShowGUI(ArrayList<Double>[] i) {


        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(" ODESolver ");

        // Create and set up the content pane.
        Graph demo = new Graph();
        frame.setContentPane(demo.createContentPane(i));

        // The other bits and pieces that define how the JFrame will work and what it will look like.
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(1300, 650);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

Comment: You need an instance of mainframe

Comment: But Mainframe creates an instance of Graph, so won't that cause a problem and if so, is there no other way?

Answer (score 0):

Instantiate MainFrame

```
MainFrame mainFrame = new MainFrame();
double lambda = mainFrame.lambdaD;
```

Comment: That will fix the compilation error, but it will probably not do what the OP wants. My guess is that there is already an instance of MainFrame somewhere, and that he needs the mabdaD value of this instance.

Comment: @bluesh34: if the graph needs to get a value from the MainFrame instance that creates it, then the MainFrame instance should be passed as argument of the Graph constructor or method. To be able to talk to John, you need to have John. So if John wants to hear something from you it should come and see you, and ask you to talk to him. Of course, if all you need in Graph is the current value of labdaD, lambdaD could also be passed as argument to the constructor/method, instead of the whole MainFrame instance.

Comment: My program worked fine. Then I wanted to improve it so that the title of the graph doesn't say y = -lambda*y but y = -0.1y or wahtever value lambdaD actually takes. Since graph extends Applet, I suppose it used the Applet constructor. If I write a new constructor, I'm concerned that it will not work anymore, but I guess there's only one way to find out. Eclipse did suggest a new constructor, but I thought I'd try looking for another method first. +1 for advice though. @JB Nizet

Comment: But Mainframe creates an instance of Graph, so won't that cause a problem? @Jixi

Answer (score 0):

If the graph needs to get a value from the MainFrame instance that creates it, then the MainFrame instance should be passed as argument of the Graph constructor or method.

(Answered in comment by JB Nizet)

Answer (score -1):

In your method `createContentPane` and the code below

```
double lambda = MainFrame.lambdaD;
```

is giving the error.
It is because you are not creating the object of type `MainFrame` for calling its property   lambdaD.

Try::

```
 double lambda = new MainFrame().lambdaD;
```

Comment: But an instance of MainFrame has already been created, which creates an instance of Graph. It's the lambdaD from the MainFrame already instantiated that I need to get.